# Extracting desired LiDAR points with Quick Terrain Modeler

Tags: clip, lidar, volume, quick-terrain-modeler

There may not be a 'better' or 'easier' way to do what I'm asking, but I figured I'd give it a shot and ask around.

I'm using Quick Terrain Modeler v8.0.3.4 (x64) and have used the ZEB1 Handheld LiDAR wand to create a cloud point dataset. As can be seen from the images, the scan is from a storage unit that holds salt. My end-state is to use the "Volume Calculation Analysis" tool in QTM in order to determine how much salt is in this (and any other) particular unit. I have successfully done this, my question however is:

***"Is there an easier way to remove LiDAR points that are not pertinent to the volume calculation?"***

For example, the way I did it was by using the 'Polygon (Screen)' tool, selecting points that were not salt, and then using the 'Cut' tool, repeat, etc. This is a very tedious process and certainly not an extremely effective way to go about obtaining or achieving the same results every iteration.

[image: Untouched salt shed scan]

[image: Finished product, salt only]

[image: Polygon/Cut]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Arcscene:

Convert '.las' point cloud file in '.lasd' format (LAS dataset). Then, add this LAS dataset in ArcScene and digitize a 3D polygon around your salt feature. Open the attribute table of such polygon and in a new field multiply the value of area and length to compute the required volume.