# Calculate the volume of a surface above an irregular surface

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, spatial-analyst, lidar, volume

I am working with repeat LiDAR data over a dune field. From the LiDAR I have generated a DEM with approximately 30cm accuracy over the entire dune field and generated a TIN from this as well. I need to know the volume of the active dune surface to determine if over the last 10 years the volume of the dune field has changed. To do this I need to know the volume of the dunes above the interdune surface. This is the surface the active dunes are moving over and is exposed between the dunes. I have made a raster of this surface by putting a point at each interdune and generating with the nearest neighbor. I now want to know that volume of the dune field above this surface. However, I only can figure out how to do this with a flat reference plane.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The elevation of the interdune  is constant over time?

Comment: Is the interdune accurately represented by a point/flat plane? Or would an interdune surface better represent what you are trying to model?

Comment: Your last paragraph has been removed because it is effectively advertising for a collaborator. It is fine to do that in the GIS Chat Room but not within the focused Q&A format of the Main site here.

Comment: Please, respond to comments by editing your question, and also add some screenshots to clarify what you want to do. For example, here is a related question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149372/extracting-desired-lidar-points-with-quick-terrain-modeler. Tks.